# "Study background" vs "study experience"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am writing essay and I need to write there about *study background* and *study, work experience*.

Is there any difference between them? If yes could you explain me that?

Comment: Probably you are looking at the difference between education and work experience. But a little more context would help confirm that. Can you edit your question to provide that? Also, some clarification would be nice: are we contrasting "study background" with "*study* experience" or "*work* experience"? Or both? I think the way your question is worded is a bit confusing.

Comment: On the web we generally avoid using all caps as it is a sign of "shouting" and is often considered rude. If you need to emphasize text, you can use quotes or use text markup in posts like bold and italics. You can also set your text apart in a quote box.

Answer (score 1):

You can say you have experience in X if you've done X before.  X is typically something specific.

You can say you have a background in X if you've done X for a long time, and have deep knowledge about X.  X is typically not something specific like a single type of job or single subject here.

> I have experience with Visual Basic (one programming language).
>
> I have a background in computer programming (implies you know multiple languages and/or can learn new ones easily).